# Copiar texto de pagina e colar em outra com JAVA ou Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Como Eu faço para copiar um texto de uma pagina da Web e colar em um input em outra pagina, com java ou Selenium WebDriver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Vamos supor que a ID do 'copiar daqui' é 'celphone-number'. E a do 'colar aqui' é 'new-celphone-number'.

Você vai primeiro pegar esse elemento (copiar daqui) normalmente através de `webelement + driver.findelement`, depois disso você vai associar esse novo elemento à uma String e usar o `getattribute("Atributo que quer")`. No meu caso, descobri o atributo assim:

```
<input id="celphone-number" class="phone depends" type="text" maxlength="11" **value**="9-8889-8989" name="celphone-number" data-depends="#check-sms"/>
```

Logo ficou: `getattribute("value")`.

No fim, achei o elemento responsável pelo novo campo de telefone, e usei um `sendkeys` mandando a variável criada. Veja o código que fica mais fácil entender.

Veja abaixo:

```
WebElement getphone = driver.findElement(By.id("celphone-number"));
String getphonetext = getphone.getAttribute("value");

WebElement newphone = driver.findElement(By.id("new-celphone-number"));
newphone.clear();
newphone.sendKeys(getphonetext);
```